# Codeigniter 3 authentication app: loggedin state does not persist across pages

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a *Codeigniter 3 authentication application*. I am new to CI, so the problems are run into are "rookie" level.

The newest one is: if a user has signed in, even though he/she is redirected to the *members area*, the signed in state does not persist. Navigating to the home page (or on any another page) *signs the user out*.

Once the user is logged in, I *don't* want the login form page to be accessible.

The sessions library is globally loaded.

The user model is:

```
class Usermodel extends CI_Model {
 public function user_login($email, $password)
  {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password));
        return $query->row();
  }
}
```

The controller looks like this:

```
class Signin extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct()
  {
      parent::__construct();
  }

  public function index()
  {
      $this->load->view('signin');
  }

  public function signin()
  {  
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');
      if ($this->form_validation->run())
      {
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $this->load->model('Usermodel');
            $current_user = $this->Usermodel->user_login($email, $password);
            if ($current_user) {
              $current_user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id', $current_user->id);
              $current_user_email = $this->session->userdata('email', $current_user->email);
              redirect('home');
          } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("signin_failure", "Incorrect email or password");
            $this->load->view('signin'); 
          }
      }
      else
      {
        $this->load->view('signin');
      }
  }
}
```

The login form view:

```
<?php echo form_open('Signin/signin'); ?>

    <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('email')) echo 'has-error';?>">
        <?php echo form_input(array(
            'name' => 'email',
            'id' => 'email',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'autocomplete' => 'off',
            'placeholder' => 'Email address'
            ));
        if(form_error('email')) echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>';
        echo form_error('email'); ?> 
    </div>

    <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('password')) echo 'has-error';?>">
        <?php echo form_password(array(
            'name' => 'password',
            'id' => 'password',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'autocomplete' => 'off',
            'placeholder' => 'Password'
            ));
        if(form_error('password')) echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>';
        echo form_error('password'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_submit(array(
            'name' => 'login',
            'value' => 'Login',
            'class' => 'btn btn-success btn-block'
            )); ?>
        </div>

    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Why is the  loggedin state not kept? Thank you!

UPDATE
User Helper:

```
function is_logged_in() {
 $CI =& get_instance();
 $user = $CI->session->userdata('user_data');
 return isset($user);
}
```

The navigation bar code:

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <?php if(is_logged_in()) : ?>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Hello, user
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">My contacts</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">All contacts</a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/Signin/signout'); ?>" title="Signout">Signout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <?php else: ?>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Register</a></li>
      <?php endif;?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image: The "Login" button should not be there]

Comment: You don't show session data for the user being set. Where does that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Just after validating whether username and password matches, you have to set data in session, for that you need, small correction:

```
// if found in table, then save it session
// so that it can be accessible from elsewhere
if ($current_user) {

     $this->session->set_userdata(
         array(
            'user_id' => $current_user->id
            'email'=> $current_user->email
        )
     );
 }
```

2. To check whether user logged in or not in all other controller, best way is to create helper, and call helper function to validate logged in user.

So for that in `helpers` directory, say you create file `user_helper.php`, with below code

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

function is_logged_in() {

    $CI =& get_instance();

    $user = $CI->session->userdata('user_data');

    return isset($user);  
}
```

3. Open file `config/autoload.php` and add your helper so that in all other controller you can it easily:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('user');
```

So in any controller you can easily check whether user logged in or not like below

```
if(is_logged_in()){
      // proceed authenticated
}else{
        // redirect to signin page or somewhere else as per your wish
        redirect('signin');
}
```

You said :

> Once the user is logged in, I don't want the login form page to be
>   accessible.

So you need

```
public function signin()
{ 
     if(is_logged_in()){

          $this->session->set_flashdata('message_name', 'You already logged In');

          //redirect to some function
          redirect("controller/function_name");

     }

     // if not logged in then display form
     // your other code goes here..

}
```

and in your view file where you redirect

```
echo $this->session->flashdata('message_name');
```

Comment: `if(is_logged_in()){
      // proceed authenticated
}else{
        // redirect to signin page or somewhere else as per your wish
        redirect('signin');
}`
does the oposit of what it should. The helper might not be recognized. CI version is 3.0.1

Comment: @RazvanZamfir: I didn't get you, in CI 3 also it supports helper

Comment: It does the exact opposite.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir you are not getting my point see update now, last part

Comment: Where does `'user_data` in `$user = $CI->session->userdata('user_data');` come from?

Comment: the `user_data` field is used for all your extra session params, suppose you set `$this->session->set_userdata('user_id',123); $this->session->set_userdata('email','someemail@example.com');`, then session will be stored like this, `'user_data' => ['user_id'=>123, 'email'=>'someemail@example.com']`, so whenever you set new data, `user_data` will be changed,  hope you got

Answer (score 0):

You Need to set userdata first.

change

```
 $current_user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id', $current_user->id);
          $current_user_email = $this->session->userdata('email', $current_user->email);
```

to

```
 $current_user_id = $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $current_user->id);
          $current_user_email = $this->session->set_userdata('email', $current_user->email);
```